# Something with my php 7.0.2

Tags: php, html

I just installed PHP 7.0.2 Apache on my Windows and everything I visit,
 like index.php I get the source code so PHP info() will show me
 `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<style type="text/css">`
 and all other html tags..
I don't know what I did but PHP 7.0.1 worked fine for me. I tried to use the older php.ini but that didnt work and still had the same problem. I though first it would be something in my .htaccess but also not the problem.

I also tried to put PHP 7.0.1 back and now even that version doesn't work.

Comment: "Get the source code" sounds like you see PHP source, eg <?php echo "Hello World!"; ?> but your example shows html source. Is the "source code" always HTML or do you also see the PHP code? Also, your question could use a better title/summary.

Comment: Add 
"DefaultType text/html" to your htaccess and see if it makes a diff